# How to set subset in istios EnvoyFilter based on a Header

Tags: istio, envoyproxy, servicemesh

I try to route traffic to different subsets of my service but I cannot use VirtualService as I need to handle the wildcard hostname *.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local. That's because there are different dynamic services in the namespace that all route to the same Pods.

So I try to set the subnet via EnvoyFilter but I didn't find the correct filter yet and the lua filter does not seem to have the ability to set the subnet. Do I have to set the envoy cluster or is there any other option I could try?'
Does the request_handle has a property/function to set the subset? Where Do I find the documentation for that?